# how to write this if else statement in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Does anyone know how to write an if else statement in R where if the departure delay is more than 15 minutes then the airline has to pay $75 for every minute delayed and if the departure delay is less than 15 minutes then there is no charge?

This is what I wrote but its throwing an error

```
mutate(`Departure Delay charges`= if_else(`departure_delay`>= '16'|`DEP_DELAY`<='15',75*`departure_delay`, "0" ))
```

Comment: And exactly what is the error being thrown.  @akrun's comment about character columns is apposite.  Remember `"9"` > `"10"` but `10` > `9`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need > 15 mins, then the second dep_delay is not necessary. If true it will multiply departure_delay by 75, it it is FALSE - it will stay 0.

```
DepartureDelayCharges = ifelse(departure_delay >= 16, 75*departure_delay, 0)
```